# how to force make mongodb replicaset instance from secondary to primary

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have mongo1 as primary (priority 3), mongo 2 (priority 2), mongo 3 (priority 1). I have mongo 1 and mongo2 in one region and I have to shut down both the instances to check if mongo3 is becoming primary automatically, but it's not. I could see that the mongo1 and mongo2 are unreachable and mongo 3 is still secondary. How can I make mongo 3 as primary.

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Answer (score 0):

`mongo 3` in your experiment will never become primary because it cannot see a majority of the quorum. For a replica set member to become a primary the essential criteria is that it is part of the majority group, otherwise it will think that, it is the one which has been disconnected from the majority group (a.k.a Network Partition - the `P` in CAP theorem) and hence remains secondary to avoid accepting any writes from clients.

So if you have a replica set of 3 members, one goes down, the other two should be able to talk to each other to ascertain that they form the majority. It is for this same reason that a replica set with even number of members is not recommended.